# How to use pos_weight argument in BCEWithLogitsLoss for increased precision

Tags: pytorch

I have a binary segmentation problem. The content of my output is either 0 or 1 in a 2D mask . My classes are heavily imbalanced: class 1 occurs 34 times more than class 0. According to the BCeWithLogitsLoss documentation:

> pos_weight (Tensor, optional) – a weight of positive examples. Must be
> a vector with length equal to the number of classes. torch.Tensor —
> PyTorch 1.11.0 documentation

further is see:

> p_c ​ > 1 increases the recall, p_c < 1 increases the precision.

where

> p_c​ is the weight of the positive answer for the class c.

and the example look like this:

> For example, if a dataset contains 100 positive and 300 negative
> examples of a single class, then pos_weight for the class should be
> equal to 300/100=3. The loss would act as if
> the dataset contains 3×100=300 positive
> examples.

In my personal case I want increased recall, so I guess it should be:

```
pos_weight=torch.tensor(34)
nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_weight)
```

But how should it be for increased precision (p_c < 1)?

Comment: It should be lower than 1 to increase precision. There is indeed no magical solution to find the value you are looking for. Have you tried lowering `p_c` to compare with the vanilla use case?

Comment: Hi @Ivan. I suppose that a weighting of 34 in my case would give equal importance to both 0 and 1. But would pos_weight=0.5 mean that 0 is favored over 1 by twice the importance?